# nginx with nagvis configuration rewrite

Tags: configuration, nginx

I want to run nagvis on nginx.

My current configuration looks like this:

```
# Nagvis Configuration
location /nagvis {
    alias /opt/nagvis/share;
}

location ~ ^(/nagvis/.*\.php)(.*)$ {
    root /opt/nagvis/share/;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap-php.sock;
}
```

The requested URL is: ..localhost/nagvis/index.php
Directed to the filesystem: /opt/nagvis/share
But then the index.php includes config.php which redirects to
..localhost/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php which results in an 404 file not found error. The logs tells me that it is looking for a total different place.

So why does it delete the "nagvis" url part, and how to get a correct rewrite for that?